# Location in a vector of a certain value, applying the mentioned location to extract the value from another vector

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector

```
   a <- seq(from =1, to = 25, by = 2)
   [1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25
```

and I would like to extract the location number (coordinates) that coincides with the value/s of 11 that occur in the vector, what do I have to do? match points out where it is in the vector but does not provide the coordinates

```
   match(a, 11)
   [1] NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

In addition I would like using the coordinates extracted from the prior example to extract the value from another vector (similar coordinates).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`match` does indeed give you the "position of (first) matches of its first argument in its second". If you swap 11 and 'a' in your `match` call , you get the (first) position of 11 in 'a':

```
match(11, a)
# [1] 6
```

From `?which`: "for a scalar `a` [11 in your case], `match(a, x)` is equivalent to `min(which(x == a))` but much more efficient".

However, if you want positions for all matches, use `which`.

@Jilber has provided an answer for how to use positions (obtained by e.g. `which` or `match`) or a logical vector for subsetting. You can read more about subsetting [**here**](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) and here: `?Extract`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `which` and `[`

```
> which(a==11)  # extracting location of value 11
[1] 6
```

The following answers your second questiont

```
> other.vector[which(a==11)] # extracting the 11th element from another vector
```

or directly

```
> other.vector[a==11]
```